# Solaris 11.1 Install Error (USB)

Tags: solaris, bios, solaris-11

I'm trying to install Solaris 11.1 on a Supermicro SYS-1027GR-TR2 from the LiveDVD.  It is not on Oracle's HCL but it is on Supermicro's Solaris 11.1 supported list.

At the beginning of LiveDVD boot, it probes for devices and is getting hung up on what I believe is USB.  "(hubd0): Connecting device on port 0 failed".  It stays on this warning message and doesn't proceed.

Normally I would just disable USB in the BIOS and do the install but the problem is I am connected over IPMI Console Redirection which uses Virtual USB for the KB/Mouse/DVdDrive.  So I can't just disable USB in the BIOS for the install.

The server does not have PS/2 interfaces and I don't have a DB9 cable handy.

I cannot even get to a shell, though I can get to the Grub command line if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had to disable the SCU in the BIOS.